# How to access value of xml element in PHP?

Tags: php, json, xml

I'm creating the XML parser and I need to get the value of element, but I can't.

```php
$dataURL = "<item internal-id='187'>Test</item>";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($dataURL, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
print_r($json);
die();
```

returns me:

```
{"@attributes":{"internal-id":"187"},"0":"Test"}
```

but

```php
$dataURL = "<item internal-id='187'><room value='187'>Test2</room></item>";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($dataURL, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
print_r($json);
die();
```

returns me

```
{"@attributes":{"internal-id":"187"},"room":"Test2"}
```

I expect to see value of all XML elements, but I still don't get them.

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting, but converting to json (and back again) is not needed at all.  In your example you can just use `echo "value=".(string)$xml.", id=".$xml['internal-id'];` to see the values, but not sure what you are expecting or trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlRe, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
                $json = json_encode($xml);
             //   $response = json_decode($json, TRUE);( for getting the results in an array format.)
```

please try this.

Thanks

Comment: It returns
```
Array
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [internal-id] => 187
        )

    [room] => Test2
)
``` I need to get value of room

Comment: Yes, for getting the JSON response you should not use json_decode function. By this, you will get the desire response.